# How to make NumPy create a matrix with Strings and floats

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matrix

All right, I've done quite a bit of research on the subject, and I'm aware that NumPy only supports homogeneous matrices.

I'm working with in Python with the NLTK package to deal with some corpus linguistics data, and simply want to make a matrix with different Strings as the 'column names' and the actual data values (floats) as the rest of the matrix.

So far, I've made two matrices, one with the Strings and one with the floats, and used vstack to put them on top of each other. All was fine and dandy until I tried using NumPy's savetxt() method with this new 'matrix' of stacked matrices, but it won't write the .csv file because the matrix is not 'matrix-like' in that it's not homogeneous. FML.

I really want to be able to use NumPy for all the awesome methods it has for dealing with the actual data points, but I can't get a freakin' array of Strings to get put at the top of the matrix to turn into a .csv.  Any ideas? I'd really love to not have to try this all again by making Python's list-of-lists approach to multidimensional arrays.

Here is the code:

```
import os.path
import sys
import nltk
from numpy import *
from nltk.corpus.reader import CHILDESCorpusReader
from nltk.probability import ConditionalFreqDist, FreqDist

n_rows = 12
n_cols = 19
init_row = 0
init_col = 0
neg_words = ["Age", "MLU", "All    Tokens","no","not","don't","can't","won't","isn't","wasn't","wouldn't","shouldn't","couldn't","didn't","haven't","aren't","haven't","hasn't","doesn't"]

Matrix_headers = array(range(len(neg_words)), dtype='a12')
Matrix_values = zeros(n_rows*n_cols).reshape((n_rows, n_cols)) #the matrix with the data    points (floats)

for entry in range(len(neg_words)):
    Matrix_headers[entry] = neg_words[entry]

p = neg_words
q = Matrix_values
Matrix = vstack([p,q])


out_name = "/Users/nicholasmoores/Documents/Research/neg_table.csv"
savetxt(out_name, Matrix, fmt='%.3e',delimiter = "\t")

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: How about `pandas`' `DataFrame`?

Comment: Yes you should use pandas for this

Comment: I was just finally able to download and install pandas so I'll try out the pandas DataFrame. My whole point was that I didn't want to have to pump this into a DataFrame in R so I'm really excited that Pandas exists

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)

e.g:

```
>>> ym = np.zeros(len(neg_words), dtype=[('heads','a14'),('vals','f4',(n_rows,))])

array([('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])], 
      dtype=[('heads', 'S14'), ('vals', '<f4', (12,))])
```

To set header values:

```
ym['heads'] = neg_words
```

To access headers:

```
>>> ym['heads']
array(['Age', 'MLU', 'All    Tokens', 'no', 'not', "don't", "can't",
   "won't", "isn't", "wasn't", "wouldn't", "shouldn't", "couldn't",
   "didn't", "haven't", "aren't", "haven't", "hasn't", "doesn't"], 
   dtype='|S14')
```

Similarly, to access values

```
ym['vals']
```